# flask-login repeatedly asks for username

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have the following code:

**user.py**

```
class User(Base, UserMixin):
    username = StringField(max_length=10, required=True, unique=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=32, required=True)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=32, required=True)

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username
```

**app.py**

```
app = Flask(
    __name__,
    static_folder='./static',
    template_folder='./static/templates'
)
app.config.from_pyfile(CONFIG_FILE)
app.register_blueprint(LOGIN)


@app.before_request
def request_setup():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        g.user = current_user.get_id()
    else:
        g.user = None

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login.user_login'


@lm.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    return LoginController.get_user(username)
```

**login_controller.py**

```
LOGIN = Blueprint('login', __name__)

class LoginController(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_user(username):
        return User.objects(username=username).first()

    @staticmethod
    @LOGIN.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def user_login():
        if request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('login.html')

        username = request.form.get('username')
        user = User.objects(username=username).first()
        if not user:
            flash('User does not exist!', 'error')
            return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            login_user(user)
            return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
```

**index.html**

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class="item">My Profile</a>
    <a class="item" href="{{ login.user_logout }}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a class="item" id="login_button">Register/Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

As far as I can see, I have everything set up right. However, logging-in does not seem to actually do anything.

- The `current_user` is still the anonymous user.
- The `Register/Login` link still shows up, instead of the `My Profile` link.
- For other parts of the site, where I have set `@login_required`, it still redirects me to the login page.

Help?

Comment: Write the result of print(user) after user = User.objects(username=username).first()

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik it prints out the user's name (my name): ` * Debugger PIN: 261-357-181
Khushalani, Sagar
- - [04/Apr/2017 14:49:07] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -`

Comment: pass to load_user() user_id , not username

Comment: Thanks @NarnikGamarnik. I'll give that a shot and report back

Comment: That made no difference. It still remains logged out.

Comment: get_id() must be return id, not username!
Try:     def get_id(self):
        return self.id

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik that worked! Thank you so much. Can you put your comment as an answer, and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def get_id(self)` must be return id, not username. Try this:

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.id
```

The following is written in the [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> get_id()
>       This method must return a unicode that **uniquely identifies this user**, and can be used to load the user from the user_loader callback.
>   Note that this must be a unicode - if the ID is natively an int or
>   some other type, you will need to convert it to unicode.